# How do I move a child object with navigation property in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two persons that can have an Atendee record. I want to merge these two, keeping the main Atendee if he has, else using the secondary's atendee. Then delete the secondary.

In SQL i would write it like this:

```
UPDATE dbo.atendee SET personid = @main.id WHERE id = @person.atendeeid
DELETE FROM people WHERE id = @person.id
```

I tried the following in EF, but get's an error:

```
    if (person.AtendeeId != null)
    {
        if (main.AtendeeId == null)
        {
            main.AtendeeId = person.AtendeeId;
            main.Atendeed = person.Atendeed;
        }
        person.AtendeeId = null;
        person.Atendeed = null;
    }

    db.Persons.Remove(person);
```

The error is:

> A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: A primary key
>   property that is a part of referential integrity constraint cannot be
>   changed when the dependent object is Unchanged unless it is being set
>   to the association's principal object. The principal object must be
>   tracked and not marked for deletion

Can someone explain what the best practice is when moving a child?

In the C# POCO's. Person has

```
public virtual int? AtendeeId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("Id")]
public virtual Atendee Atendeed { get; set; }
```

While atendee has:

```
public virtual int PersonId { get; set; }
public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
```

In SQL Atendees has a

```
PersonId(int, not null)
```

And People has a

```
Atendeeid(int, null)
```

Comment: what is the point of merging 2 Persons if you want to remove 2nd Person afterwards.  Cannot you just remove the 2nd person? But please try with setting AtendeeId to main object. I wouldn't modify person.AtendeeiId nor Atendeed  properties because it will be done automatically after removing person object.

Comment: Then I loose the Atendee information that I want to transfer to the 2nd Person. What do you mean about setting AtendeeId?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the navigation properties to effect the move, not the FKs. Be sure to eager-load the children in both cases. So if a Person is set to have a Optional Attendee where Person holds AttendeeId, then your logic to move an attendee from one person to the other:

```
targetPerson.Attendee = sourcePerson.Attendee;
sourcePerson.Attendee = null;
context.SaveChanges();
```

Where both Target and source were retrieved with attendee eager loaded:

```
var targetPerson = context.People.Include(x=>x.Attendee).SingleOrDefault(x=>x.PeopleId == targetId);
var sourcePerson = context.People.Include(x=>x.Attendee).SingleOrDefault(x=>x.PeopleId == sourceId);
```

With the relevant checks to ensure that an attendee exists prior to transfer. EF works these operations out best through the navigation properties and their proxy classes and representation in the context tracking rather than trying to do this by ID.

Comment: Turned out my problem was code first generating a bad DB. For some reason the FK from atendee to person was the ID column of atendee, instead of the personId column of the atendee table.